# Django : Define DateTimeField default value as None or blank field

Tags: python, django

I would like to define a new field in my models.py file.

**Case 1 :**

```
download_date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name=_('download date'), null=True, default=None)
```

This field should be `None` or `Blank` field when an object is saved into my database.

If I write my field like above, it gives :

> null value in column "download_date" violates not-null constraint

**Case 2 :**

If I add `blank = True`, I get the same issue

> null value in column "download_date" violates not-null constraint

What I have to write in order to get a blank/empty field ?

Thank you

Comment: That's the way to do it. Sounds like you didn't migrate after making your changes.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Pretty strange because the `makemigrations/migrate` process seems to work fine.

Comment: I dropped my database and created a new one, it seems to work. As you said, maybe an issue according to my migration files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

setting null=True and blank=True it is the way to do this.

But in your case, you said that you did run the migrations. So it seems that the not null constraint is already in the database.

Sometimes, you might get into this situation when altering your database schema, making changes to migrations files and django cannot detect it correctly and reports no changes detected.

You might need to look at the your database to verify this.

Probably, the easier way out is to create new  database and run migrations again.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer : what I've done is good, but I had an issue according to my migration files. I dropped the database and created a new one and i works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Setting null and blank as True should work in your case.